# Ktor Keycloak Acess Token Route Protection

Tags: kotlin, keycloak, access-token, ktor

I'm using a server that authenticates through keycloak. In keycloak I have created a realm and am able to get an Access token as a response. This access token gets fed now into my Ktor application.

However, I'm not quite sure how to protect routes in an easy manner. I want to have some protected routes that have a `authenticate("keycloakOAuth"){}` scope around it which handles validating the access token and refreshing using the refresh token if the access token is expired.

Currently I have keycloak inside Ktor configured as this:

```
        authenticate("keycloakOAuth") {
            get("login") {}

            route("/callback") {
                // This handler will be executed after making a request to a provider's token URL.
                handle {
                    val principal = call.authentication.principal<OAuthAccessTokenResponse>()

                    if (principal != null) {
                        val response = principal as OAuthAccessTokenResponse.OAuth2
                        call.respondText { "Access token: ${response.accessToken}" }
                    } else {
                        call.respondText { "NO principal" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This works fine because when I go to login I'm getting sent to the Keycloak login page and I can login. When I logged in the callback executes and I get my Access Token back.

When I'm trying to protect routes however, some odd stuff happens. I know that I need to validate the incoming JWT token. But I have no clue how to given the Ktor capabilities. The examples are also of little help, since they are quite vague.

Currently I have something like this:

```
        authenticate("keycloakOAuth") {
            get("/testAuth") {
                val principal = call.authentication.principal<OAuthAccessTokenResponse.OAuth2>()
                if(principal != null) {
                    call.respondText("Authenticated!")
                } else {
                    call.respondText("Unauthenticated...")
                }
            }
        }
```

But my application will always send me to the login page and then callback page, even though I am sending the Bearer token when I'm testing this call.

My question is:

How do I protect routes in a manner that they need a valid token, with the same syntax that Ktor uses (like authenticate(){}). Do I need to configure JWT for this?

Answer (score 1):

When you request one of the routes under `authenticate`, the full cycle of OAuth authentication is triggered. This is because the `Authentication` plugin is designed so a client sends credentials and gets authenticated for each request. For some reason, OAuth integration was implemented on top of the `Authentication` plugin hence such unexpected behavior.

To solve your problem you can have only `/login` and `/callback` routes restricted. In the callback's handler save user ID and tokens in a [session](https://ktor.io/docs/sessions.html) or in any other storage for future use. For other routes, you can check manually the fact that a user is authenticated and then use tokens from storage to acquire protected data from the resource server. For convenience, you can create some [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html) to minimize the amount of boilerplate code. Unfortunately, there is no built-in functionality to make it work out of the box.

You don't need to configure JWT for this.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll be using sessions from now on to get the user's information. However, in terms of validating the token. How can I do this? I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59331971/9372943) that they use verifyOffline with a certificate. But I'd like to know how to do this in the Java version I've found [this](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.keycloak/keycloak-core/latest/org/keycloak/TokenVerifier.html) thus far.

Comment: I suggest reading an article https://ktor.io/docs/jwt.html about JWT in Ktor's documentation.