# JWT and authentication safety/patterns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, authentication, jwt

Im building an authentincation and authorization system in javacript using JWT token
basically when i login i store in httponly cookies:

- JWT Token
- JWT Refresh Token
- user information (id, username, email)
- JWT expiration (5 minutes from when it's generated)

When the JWT is still valid protected pages will do a remote check for user validity (i request an API passing the userId and the auth token as an authorization bearer)
the remote check can take some time (less than a second), but every protected page shows a loading spinner while checking; i was wondering how safe is assuming the user is logged in it the JWT is still valid (or the refresh token get a new JWT) and the cookie with the user data is present. No external requests involved, unless you need to refresh the JWT

Comment: Refresh tokens make no sense if they are stored and accessed the same way as the access token. Why is user info a separate cookie (is it)? How is expiration stored and checked? Why are you using JWTs at all when it sounds like a plain old session with a random id would be a lot simpler and more secure?

Comment: The answers of this come to my mind https://stackoverflow.com/q/71293140/2290153 are you in the same Project?

Comment: i use the jwt because it is requested as a header for some API requests, that's all.
I can keep user data in the same cookie too, also i can move the refresh token to a different storage (but why? isnt the httponly cookie the most safa place?)

Comment: @MatthiasWiedemann not in the same project...
anyways, all the answers i read here are explaining me what a jwt is and is not, but no one is giving me an answer about my problem.... i have a jwt (provided by an api), a refresh token, user data somewhere on my client, i need to get a protected page, should i remotely authorize the user with jwt+user or not? thats all...

Comment: @GaborLengyel i use jwt because some API requests need it; expiration and refreshing the jwt is fully automated (if the request come along with an expired jwt, the reply inform my app, that request a new jwt and redo the initial request with it (i aslo can add a soft check by storing somewhere the expiration time and checking it before the request, in any case the jwt i checked remotely even if i tamper the local expiration date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i was wondering how safe is assuming the user is logged in it the JWT is still valid (or the refresh token get a new JWT) and the cookie with the user data is present

JWTs are not fit as a mechanism of managing sessions. A JWT has its own expiration time and this is regardless of the user's session. If you need to manage a user's session, just use mechanisms for sessions, and scrap the JWT.

Comment: ok, in fact im not using jwt as a session, it is used as an authorization header in api requests. keeping the jwt, the refreshtoken and a the user data somewhere on client, should i remotely check on every page (that do not need ti query remote data) if i am still logged (usually sending a request to an endpoint with my jwt and user data), or i can assume im logged if i have these data on my client side?

Comment: Usually, you can safely assume that the user is logged in if you have their data in the client. Once the user makes a request it will be verified if the token is indeed valid, and, if needed, you will be able to refresh it.

Comment: thank you... that's what i was thinking, for non  critial requests (showing username, navigation bars and so on) i wont check remotely, of course if i need remote data i will have to pass the jwt and so on